# Extracting Multiple Dates from a single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a single cell that is including all historical updates, each update displays a date/time stamp and then the user's name before their notes. I need to extract all the date/time/name stamps to total their occurrences. **+EDIT+** I need to get the name and date portion from each stamp so that i am able to chart the information in a pivot table. **Output of something like; "3/3/2016 Rachel Boyers; 3/2/2016 Rachel Boyers; 3/2/2016 James Dorty"**

EX: 
"**3/3/2016 9:28:36 AM  Rachel Boyers:**  EEHAW! Terri replied!!! Hello Rachel, 
I cannot find a match using the 4232A or the 12319 part number. **3/2/2016 7:39:06 AM  Rachel Boyers:**  Sent EM to Terri - Eng per EM reply. **3/2/2016 7:35:06 AM  James Dorty:**  2/29/16 sent another EM to Kim. Received Auto response as follows: Thank you for your mail. Kim **12/7/2015 12:26:25 PM  Frank De La Torre:**  Again VM - pushing FU out until after the holidays.

Comment: Look like `: ` is your key.

Comment: Along with @findwindow - look into [Text to Columns](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/text-to-columns.html), probably using `Space` as a delimiter.

Comment: @findwindow I thought " AM " or " PM " was the key.

Comment: @ForwardEd Ah, yea, that helps to grab the name. Edit: or you know just regex =P

Comment: also helps grab the time...just count backwards

Answer (score 5):

### **Edited based on added information**

Edit (5/16/2016): I made some changes to the code, as you'll find below. One change, based on the new information, allows you to use the `JoinArrayWithSemiColons` function as either a standard worksheet function, or as function to be used in a module. So, what does this mean? It means that (assuming your cell to parse is `A1`), in cell `B1` you can write a function like `=JoinArrayWithSemiColons(A1)` just like you'd write a normal worksheet function. However, if you'd still like to perform the action over a range of cells using VBA, you can run a procedure like `TestFunction()` as found in the code posted below. Also note, the `ExtractDateTimeUsers` function doesn't necessarily ever need to be called directly by the user because it's now being used exclusively as a helper function for the `JoinArray...` function.

Let me know if this helps to clear things up a bit.

### Old Post

You can accomplish this using some Regular Expressions. See the code below for an example. In my case, I have a function to return a multidimensional array of results. In my test procedure, I call this function, then assign the results to an EMPTY matrix of cells (in your test case, you will have to determine where to put it). You do NOT have to assign the result to a group of cells, but rather you can do whatever you want with the array.

```
Private Function ExtractDateTimeUsers(nInput As String) As Variant()
    Dim oReg As Object
    Dim aOutput() As Variant
    Dim nMatchCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim vMatches As Object

    Set oReg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With oReg
        .MultiLine = False
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "([0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}) ([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2} [AP]M) (.*?):"
    End With

    If oReg.Test(nInput) Then
        Set vMatches = oReg.Execute(nInput)
        nMatchCount = vMatches.Count
        ReDim aOutput(0 To nMatchCount - 1, 0 To 2)

        For i = 0 To nMatchCount - 1
            aOutput(i, 0) = vMatches(i).Submatches(0)
            aOutput(i, 1) = vMatches(i).Submatches(1)
            aOutput(i, 2) = vMatches(i).Submatches(2)
        Next i
    Else
        ReDim aOutput(0 To 0, 0 To 0)
        aOutput(0, 0) = "No Matches"
    End If


    ExtractDateTimeUsers = aOutput
End Function

Function JoinArrayWithSemiColons(sInput As String) As String
    Dim vArr As Variant

    vArr = ExtractDateTimeUsers(sInput)

    If vArr(0, 0) = "No Matches" Then
        JoinArrayWithSemiColons = "No Matches"
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Loop through array to build the output string
    For i = LBound(vArr, 1) To UBound(vArr, 1)
        sOutput = sOutput & "; " & vArr(i, 0) & " " & vArr(i, 2)
    Next i

    JoinArrayWithSemiColons = Mid(sOutput, 3)
End Function

Sub TestFunction()
    'Assume the string we are parsing is in Column A
    '(I defined a fixed range, but you can make it dynamic as you need)

    Dim rngToJoin As Range
    Dim rIterator As Range

    Set rngToJoin = Range("A10:A11")

    For Each rIterator In rngToJoin
        rIterator.Offset(, 1).Value = JoinArrayWithSemiColons(rIterator.Value)
    Next rIterator

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your help with this, I tried to implement this (however i am a complete novice in the area of VBA and programming) I was unable to get the result that i hoped for and made an edit to the question that might help you to help me! What should the output from your above regex look like?

Comment: @AaronBondy Right now, the `ExtractDateTimeUsers` function returns an array of value. If you're unfamiliar with arrays, they are essentially tables stored in memory. Right now, the "table" has three columns (one for date, one for time, and one for username), and it has one row per match. If you need the return in one long string separated by semicolons, you can do so with a helper function. I will edit my code above and hopefully that clears it up.

Comment: I see, this is great. However i have an issue using it for what i hoped because i need to get this type of data for an entire column of cells with data similar to the sample i posted. a1 - a(N) all have a string like the sample and i am hoping to get that information in a format by which i can track all date/name stamps. Is it possible to do this? the array format is great with a column for name date time by row. Any ideas?

Comment: @AaronBondy If I understand you correctly, you want ONE string to hold the result of the expression for a range of cells. If this is the case, it isn't such a difficult change. We already have a function to extract matches from the string. We also have a function to join matches with a semicolon. Now, we just need to run this over a range. Check out my newest edit. I really only had to change the `TestFunction` procedure (and also one small change to the `JoinWith...` function.

Comment: sorry my description was misleading. A1, A2 etc. contain individual strings of data similar to the sample, I would like B1, B2 ect. (or B1:Z1,B2:Z2 however is easiest) to contain the date/time/name information related to the corresponding cell in column A. I would like to keep all information related to cell A1 in row 1, and B1 in row 2 and so on down the list. PS i cant get how to use the join with semi function, do i use it in another cell referencing the array? as i said dumby = me

Comment: @AaronBondy See the revised code and information up above. I think this should resolve your question, but if not, please let us know.

Answer (score 3):

As simple (non-regex) function you can use something like this:

```
Public Function getCounts(str As String) As Variant

  Dim output() As Variant, holder As Variant, i As Long

  ReDim output(0, 0)
  holder = Split(str, " ")

  For i = 0 To UBound(holder) - 2
    If IsDate(holder(i) & " " & holder(i + 1) & " " & holder(i + 2)) Then

      If UBound(output) Then
        ReDim Preserve output(1 To 3, 1 To UBound(output, 2) + 1)
      Else
        ReDim output(1 To 3, 1 To 1)
      End If

      output(1, UBound(output, 2)) = holder(i)
      output(2, UBound(output, 2)) = holder(i + 1) & " " & holder(i + 2)
      i = i + 3

      While Right(holder(i), 1) <> ":" And i < UBound(holder)
        output(3, UBound(output, 2)) = output(3, UBound(output, 2)) & " " & holder(i)
        i = i + 1
      Wend

      output(3, UBound(output, 2)) = Trim(output(3, UBound(output, 2))) & " " & Left(holder(i), Len(holder(i)) - 1)

    End If
  Next

  If Application.Caller.Rows.Count > UBound(output, 2) Then
    i = UBound(output, 2)
    ReDim Preserve output(1 To 3, 1 To Application.Caller.Rows.Count)

    For i = i + 1 To UBound(output, 2)
      output(1, i) = ""
      output(2, i) = ""
      output(3, i) = ""
    Next

  End If

  getCounts = Application.Transpose(output)

End Function
```

Just put it in a module to use it as UDF. (Outputs a 3-column-table)

If you have any questions, just ask :)

Comment: Very nicely done indeed! Just in case the OP is wondering (just like me for a minute) how to use this: (1) copy the above code into a module (2) assuming that the comment you want to parse is in cell `A1` you should put into `B1` the following: `=INDEX(getCounts($A$1);ROW();COLUMN()-1)` (3) copy the formula across to column `D` and down to row 4 (for the above sample you gave us).

Comment: assuming the text is in A1, it will be easier to just select B1:D10 and enter `=getCounts(A1)` with ctrl + shift + enter ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it. Maybe a little slower, but short and easy to read...

```
Public Function DateCount(str As String) As Variant
Dim pos As Integer, endpos As Integer, namepos As Integer
Dim Text As String, Output() As String, counter As Integer
    pos = InStr(pos + 1, str, "/")
    Do While pos > 0
        endpos = InStr(pos + 1, str, "M ")
        Text = Mid(str, pos - 1, endpos - pos + 2)
        If IsDate(Text) Then
            counter = counter + 1
            ReDim Preserve Output(1 To 2, 1 To counter)
            namepos = InStr(endpos, str, ":")
            Output(1, counter) = Text
            Output(2, counter) = Mid(str, endpos + 2, namepos - endpos - 2)
            pos = namepos
        End If
        pos = InStr(pos + 1, str, "/")
    Loop

' Only Count
getCounts = counter
' complete List
getCounts = Output
End Function
```