# Extracting Irregular Dates Associated with Specific Words in Single Cell with Multiple Lines in Excel

Tags: regex, vba, excel

This is my first post on here, so please excuse any mistakes.

I have a column of cells. Each cell contains a variable number of lines withing the cell. Most lines contain a date. The format of the date varies slightly. Sometimes it is in the format MM/DD/YYYY, sometimes it will be MM/DD/YY, etc. My goal is to extract the date associated with a specific word in each line. Also, each cell is on a row with an identifying number. Therefore, I need the output to be along the same row.

Example:
[image: Desired Output]

I have tried every extract date formula I can find and I have run into three problems:

1. how to pull multiple dates from the cell,
2. how to compensate for the fact that some rows have dates that are formatted differently, and
3. how to pull dates only associated with certain words on the same line as the date.

It appears that my best option would be to use Regular Expressions. However, I have just started playing around with VBA and every function I have found that seems related to my issue I have been unable to adapt to my specific problem. I was using this post as a guide to build my function initially, but I cannot get it to work: [Extracting Multiple Dates from a single cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145856/extracting-multiple-dates-from-a-single-cell?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Originally, I tried breaking the lines up by doing text to column and this formula:

```
=IF(SEARCH("Red",D2),DATE(MID(D2,SEARCH("??/??/20??",D2)+6,4),MID(D2,SEARCH("??/??/20??",D2),2),MID(D2,SEARCH("??/??/20??",D2)+3,2)), "No Red Date")
```

However, text to column was not working because of irregular spacing issues. And Blue 1 and Blue 2 is just there to compensate for if there are multiple Blue dates in the cell, which there often are

Comment: What have you tried?  What defines `Blue 1` and `Blue 2` vs just `Blue`?

Comment: What VBA code have you used?  **What defines `Blue 1` and `Blue 2` vs just `Blue`** *(Edit your question to show the code.  It is pretty hard to read in the comment section)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOT AN ANSWER : It doesn't really need code, you can use `MID` `FIND` `SUBSTITUTE`  quickly playing, I used the following

`=IF(FIND(C$1,$B2,1)-11<11,MID($B2,1,10),MID($B2,FIND(C$1,$B2,1)-11,10))`

Which gives this, [image]

Comment: Wow! I am embarrassed it was that simple. I mean, there is still some variability I have to account for, but that was actually what I needed. I cannot tell you how many weird formulas I have run through to try to get this. Thank you so much.

Comment: If this is not an answer then it should not be posted as one.

Comment: @Ctala23 if this solves your problem, please click the green check mark to the left of the answer to indicate to others that it's a working solution. (also, welcome to Stack Overflow)

Comment: @TylerH I posted as an answer for improved formatting and the image.